# Git: How to find all merges of a derived branch into its derived from branch?

Tags: git, merge

Suppose a master branch and derived from branches A, B, C
I want to check when A, B, C did last merge back into master

I tried

git log --merges

on master but then I do not see the branch these merges are comming from. Any ideas?

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't deleted your local branches you can check which branches are merged into master.

```
// lists branches merged into master
git branch --merged <destination_branch>
```

---

If you deleted them or they are not local branches you cane print out all the merge log entries and track them down

```
git log --merges --first-parent
```

> **--first-parent**
>
> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit.
>   This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.

Comment: git log --merges --first-parent --oneline yields a list containing <commit hash> HEAD <commit message> the name of the parent the merge originated from is not visible, not using --oneline doesn't do it either

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when a specific branch `A` was last merged into master, do: `git merge-base master A`. That will show the commit where `A` and `master` last pointed to the same commit.